# Replace pandas column values with dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

I have a dictionary like as shown below

```
OUTPUT = {'supplier': {0: 'ABCD',
  1: 'DEFG',
  2: 'GHIK',
  3: 'JKL'},
 'region': {0: 'KOREA',
  1: 'AUS/NZ',
  2: 'INDIA',
  3: 'ASEAN',
  4: 'HK / CHINA'}}

ID,supplier,region,subject
1, 0, 3, TEST
2, 1, 2, EXAM
3, 3, 4, VIVA

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to replace the values in column `supplier` and `region` with their corresponding mapping value from the dictionary

I tried the below

```
df["supplier"].replace(output) # not works
df['supplier'].map(output) # not works
```

But this threw an error as shown below

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_replace_columnwise'

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
ID,supplier,region,subject
1, ABCD, ASEAN, TEST
2, DEFG, INDIA, EXAM
3, JKL, HK/CHINA, VIVA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map` in loop:

```
for k,v in OUTPUT.items():
    df[k] = df[k].map(v)
```

or simply use `replace` [as suggested by @piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71742199/replace-pandas-column-values-with-dictionary-values/71742238?noredirect=1#comment126785400_71742238):

```
df = df.replace(OUTPUT)
```

Output:

```
   ID supplier      region subject
0   1     ABCD       ASEAN    TEST
1   2     DEFG       INDIA    EXAM
2   3      JKL  HK / CHINA    VIVA
```

Comment: Use `df.replace(OUTPUT)`  The `to_replace` argument can be a dictionary that defines what should be replaced per column.  And that is what `OUTPUT` already is.

Comment: thanks, upvoted. I tried replace above but it didn't seem to work. We can't do column wise?

Comment: @TheGreat does it have anything to do with how your dict is `OUTPUT` but you used `output`, i.e. do you have `output` defined in your environment?